# ansible find patterns on single line?

Tags: linux, debian, ansible

How could I do this:

```
- find:
    paths: "/etc/ssl/"
    recurse: yes
    patterns:
      - "*.pem"
      - "*.crt"
```

On a single line?

The [documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/find_module.html) suggests something along:

```
- find: paths="/etc/ssl/" recurse=yes patterns="'*.pem','*.crt'"
```

But this doesn't match any of the files, while the previous command does.

Comment: Why does t need to be on a single line ?

Comment: @Iain I got most my commands on a single line for readability. Apart from that, I'd like to know what the problem with this is. (As the documentation suggests it should work)

Comment: I think you're pretty alone with the opinion that it serves readability to throw everything in a single line :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to do

```
- find: paths="/etc/ssl/" recurse=yes patterns="*.pem,*.crt"
```

The bug I [filed](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/issues/3029) has fixed this in the documentation aswell.

Answer (score 3):

The docs seem to be wrong there. I could not get it woking. It's clearly expecting a list but even a definition like `patterns=['*.pem','*.crt']` does not work.

If this really is a need, you can define it as a regular expression, that'll work:

```
- find: paths="/etc/ssl/" recurse=yes patterns=".*\.(pem|crt)" use_regex=yes
```